# System.InvalidOperationException: Failed to map the path '/'

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a web application that runs in visual studio 2010.

For tests purposes I configured a site on IIS for the same physical path used in visual studio.

After this configuration, if i start the project from visual studio i get the following error

> System.InvalidOperationException: Failed to map the path '/'.

I've tried everything I could think of, even deleting the website, but the problem persists...

Any ideias?

Comment: If you look at the stacktrace this will let you know the exact method that has failed.  If you do this you'll be able to narrow down the cause.  If not post up what you've learnt and we'll help you.

Comment: Wasn't a problem in the code... no changes where made and the site worked fine in IIS. I have posted the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After rebooting, deleting the site, changing all kinds of configurations possible, I fixed it.

The solution:

1. Open Visual Studio
2. Open Solution
3. Press F5

I usually open visual studio through the sln file. Don't know why... but it worked...

Comment: I suspect this was a file location issue, which you resolved either by deleting the site or `changing all kinds of configurations`.  Pressing F5 just builds your app.

Comment: I think you miss understood... I had the application open and it wasn't working. Then, with no change what so ever, i did those 3 steps and it worked. I think it has something to do with how you open the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem :Failed to map the path '/projectname/imagefolder/Jellyfish.jpg'. My problem was that i had done
  `fp = Server.MapPath("imag /" + fn )`;.

Just avoid the space between "image" and "/".

Hope it helps

**EDIT:**
*Seems the problem is already solved.May be it will be helpful to someone else.*